# MPNowPlayingInfoCenter nowPlayingInfo not updating at end of track

Tags: ios, swift, mpnowplayinginfocenter

I have a method that changes the audio track played by my app's `AVPlayer` and also sets `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo` for the new track:

```
func setTrackNumber(trackNum: Int) {
    self.trackNum = trackNum
    player.replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem(tracks[trackNum])

    var nowPlayingInfo: [String: AnyObject] = [ : ]        
    nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle] = tracks[trackNum].albumTitle
    nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] = "Track \(trackNum)"
    ...
    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfo 

    print("Now playing local: \(nowPlayingInfo)")
    print("Now playing lock screen: \(MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo)")   
}
```

I call this method when the user explicitly selects an album or track and when a track ends and the next one automatically starts.  The lock screen correctly shows the track metadata when the user sets an album or track but NOT when a track ends and the next one is automatically set.

I added print statements to make sure  I was correctly populating the `nowPlayingInfo` dictionary.  As expected, the two print statements print the same dictionary content when this method is called for a user-initiated change of album or track.  However, in the case when the method is called after an automatic track change, the local `nowPlayingInfo` variable shows the new `trackNum` whereas `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo` shows the previous `trackNum`:

```
Now playing local: ["title": Track 9, "albumTitle": Test Album, ...]
Now playing set: Optional(["title": Track 8, "albumTitle": Test Album, ...]
```

I discovered that when I set a breakpoint on the line that sets `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo` to `nowPlayingInfo`, then the track number is correctly updated on the lock screen.  Adding `sleep(1)` right after that line also ensures that the track on the lock screen is correctly updated.

I have verified that `nowPlayingInfo` is always set from the main queue.  I've tried explicitly running this code in the main queue or in a different queue with no change in behavior.

What is preventing my change to `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo`? How can I make sure that setting `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo` always updates the lock screen info?

**EDIT**

After going through the code for the Nth time thinking "concurrency", I've found the culprit. I don't know why I didn't get suspicious about this earlier:

```
func playerTimeJumped() {
    let currentTime = currentItem().currentTime()

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo?[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = CMTimeGetSeconds(currentTime)
    }
}

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
       self,
       selector: "playerTimeJumped",
       name: AVPlayerItemTimeJumpedNotification,
       object: nil)
```

This code updates the lock screen's time elapsed when the user scrubs or skips forward/back. If I comment it out, the `nowPlayingInfo` update from `setTrackNumber` works as expected under any condition.

**Revised questions**: how are these two pieces of code interacting when they're both run on the main queue? Is there any way I can do a `nowPlayingInfo` update on `AVPlayerItemTimeJumpedNotification` given that there will be a jump when there's a call on `setTrackNumber`?

Comment: Has anyone else experienced anything like this?

Comment: I'm speculating here but MPNowPlayingInfoCenter must presumably dispatch nowPlayingInfo changes to whatever system process manages the lock screen. So I wouldn't be at all surprised at your debug output... the setNowPlayingInfo method is effectively completing asynchronously.

Comment: When the track changes automatically, is setTrackNumber *definitely* being called every time? Even when the app is backgrounded?

Comment: @ReubenScratton - agreed that setting `nowPlayingInfo` is likely done asynchronously so the prints are not all that helpful. But I'd expect the set to complete at some point! When the phone is showing the lockscreen, I know `setTrackNumber` is always called because my debug prints show up on the console.

Comment: @HélèneMartin Not sure if it's related. Just wondering if you open "Background Modes" in "Capabilities"?

Comment: @Allen - yes, I have background audio enabled and it works great!

Comment: Just to clarify for a little more insight; what happens when, on the locked screen, the user presses the pause button? Also, when viewing the lock screen at the time when a new track is played (automatically after a track finishes playing), what is displayed on the lock screen? does the next track continue to playing?

Comment: All the buttons on the lock screen work as expected. For example, the pause button correctly pauses the currently playing track. When a new track is played automatically, the audio changes correctly but the lock screen displays the previous track's information.

Comment: @HélèneMartin look at my answer...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that `nowPlayingInfo` is updated in two places at the same time when the track automatically changes: in the `setTrackNumber` method which is triggered by `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification` and in the `playerTimeJumped` method which is triggered by `AVPlayerItemTimeJumpedNotification`.

This causes a race condition. More details are provided by an Apple staff member [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/32475).

The problem can be solved by keeping a local `nowPlayingInfo` dictionary that gets updated as needed and always setting `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo` from that instead of setting individual values.

Answer (score 1):

For background info update, my colleague suggests some implementations are necessary. Maybe you can check and verify some of these requirements in your view controller:

```
    //1: Set true for canBecomeFirstResponder func
    override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    //2: Set view controller becomeFirstResponder & allow to receive remote control events
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.becomeFirstResponder()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
        ....
    }

    //3: Implement actions after did receive events from remote control
    override func remoteControlReceivedWithEvent(event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let event = event else {
            return
        }
        switch event.subtype {
        case .RemoteControlPlay:
            ....
            break
        case .RemoteControlPause:
            ....
            break
        case .RemoteControlStop:
            ....
            break
        default:
            print("default action")
        }
    }
```

Comment: I do #2. #3 should not be directly related since it has to do with remote control events but yes, I do handle remote control events correctly. #1 and `self.becomeFirstResponder()` I don't totally understand. I think it's so that a view can receive remote control events? The `setTrackNumber` method is in a class that wraps `AVPlayer` and that I use a singleton of throughout my views.

Comment: @HélèneMartin Yeah, I know what you mean. That's what I thought at first; however, after I check Event Handling Guide for iOS from Apple (which also contains topic for responder chains). I found the topic "Providing Now Playing Information" is under the section "Remote Control Events" https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Remote-ControlEvents/Remote-ControlEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH7-SW1 Therefore, I think probably background info update might serve for Remote Control at its design concept.

Comment: @HélèneMartin Also if you are testing it in iOS Simulator, always include the MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate key in your nowPlayingInfo dictionary according to the document.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this code? This worked for my example...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

if NSClassFromString("MPNowPlayingInfoCenter") != nil {
    let albumArt = MPMediaItemArtwork(image: image) // any image
    var songInfo: NSMutableDictionary = [
        MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: "Whatever",
        MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: "Whatever",
        MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: albumArt
    ]
    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo = songInfo as [NSObject : AnyObject]
}
try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, withOptions: [])
   try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
}
```

Explanation: 
You have to check if the MPNowPlayingInfo is active due at some time it is going into background. If it is in the background then you have to make it active which does this line of code:

```
try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, withOptions: [])
       try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
```

Write me if that worked...

**Edit**

If this doesn't work you could also try this code but the code above is the more modern solution

```
if (AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)) {
    println("Receiving remote control events")
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
} else {
    println("Audio Session error.")
}
```

Here you are also trying to make it active, the same as above. This is a old version which might not work...

Comment: I do set the session's category and make it active. Please note that the track change as triggered automatically by the end of the previous track never updates the nowPlayingInfo correctly, even when the app is in the foreground.

Answer (score 1):

First off, definitely enable background modes for your app in the .plist file. This will allow your app to use background tasks and run your update code while locked.

Secondly, I would let the update function get called by the AVAudioPlayer delegate function `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:` if you want to update it at the proper time. Also you could try registering for a notification that it is finished as an alternative.

Comment: Background modes are enabled and work correctly.  I use an `AVPlayer` and the call on `setTrackNumber` is triggered by `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification`. As you can see in my revision, the problem is that two different notifications can sometimes trigger an update on `nowPlayingInfo` at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on the above answer, but when using MPRemoteCommandCenter it is not necessary to call `-[UIApplication beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents]` nor `-[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder]` to handle remote events. The above answer is referring to an older implementation that is no longer recommended.

It is recommended to set as many keys as possible in the nowPlayingInfo dictionary. `MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration`, `MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate`, and `MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime` can affect whether MPNowPlayingInfoCenter updates.

Comment: That is correct -- I use the new implementation for remote control events and they are working correctly. I set all the `nowPlayingInfo` keys I have information for including all the ones you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my case:

The `AVAudioSession` matters.

---

not this:

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
            try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback, options: AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.mixWithOthers)

            audioSession.requestRecordPermission({ (isGranted: Bool) in  })

            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: AVAudioSession.SetActiveOptions.notifyOthersOnDeactivation)

        } catch  {

        }
```

It doesn't work

---

but

```
       do {
            //keep alive audio at background
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
        } catch _ { }

        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        } catch _ { }
```

It works